# Model fitting by likelihood maximization: simultaneous fitting with two datasets

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution

My model $M$ depends on some parameters $\theta$: $M(\theta)$.

The model contains two random variables $X_{1}(t)$, $X_{2}(t)$, which vary over time $t$.

$X_{1}(t) \sim Pois(\mu_{1}(t))$ and $X_{2}(t) \sim Pois(\mu_{2}(t))$, $\mu_{1}(t)=f_{1}(t;\theta)$ and $\mu_{2}(t)=f_{2}(t;\theta)$ where $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are two functions that are know but complex.

To estimate the parameters $\theta$, the likelihood maximization method is used. The data

$x_{1,mod}(1),x_{1,mod}(2),..., x_{1,mod}(10)$ and $x_{2,mod}(1),x_{2,mod}(2),..., x_{2,mod}(10)$

produced by the model are fitted with real data

$x_{1,real}(1),x_{1,real}(2),..., x_{1,real}(10)$ and $x_{2,real}(1),x_{2,real}(2),..., x_{2,real}(10)$.

The log-likelihood is:
$$f(\theta)=\sum_{t=1}^{10} Prob(X_{1}(t)=x_{1,real}(t)|\mu_{1}(t)=x_{1,mod}(t))+\sum_{t=1}^{10} Prob(X_{2}(t)=x_{2,real}(t)|\mu_{2}(t)=x_{2,mod}(t)).$$

The problem is that as $X_{1}$ takes higher values than $X_{2}$ (around 10 for $X_{1}$ and around 100 for $X_{2}$), the probability that $X_{1}$ equals a given value $x_{1}$ will be much higher than the probability that $X_{2}$ equals a given value $x_{2}$. Thus, in the likelihood function, the former part (used for $X_{1}$) will have a bigger importance and bigger impact than the latter part (used for $X_{2}$).

How to do in order to have the same importance for both parts? Use weights?